# Operation not permitted when executing a terminal command from Xcode app

Tags: swift

I've just built an app in Swift and I use Xcode. Here's my function to execute a command:

```
func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
    let task = Process()
    let pipe = Pipe()
    
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]
    task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
    task.launch()
    
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    
    return output
}
```

But here is my problem. When I build the app and click the button, it returned this error:

```
zsh:1: Operation not permitted: /Applications/SmallGame.app/Contents/Resources/runGraphic
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint 1: Entitlement

Comment: Hint 2: Sanboxed

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Your application is not entitled to run a shell.  Perhaps if you could explain the effect you are trying to achieve we could help you get the effect another way.

Comment: I've managed to solve the problems. thanks u guys for supportive